# Find another user's most recent activity in Slack

Tags: slack

Our organization has a lot of Slack channels. Is it possible to figure out where a given user has been publicly posting most recently? For example, I'd like to search for user Bob and get a result that he posted in channel `foo` 10 minutes ago and in channel `bar` 20 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using top search bar you must type:

> from:@UserNameHere

my side I've french version:

> de:@NomUtilisateurIci

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this via third-party apps (e.g., [Phase](https://phasecrm.com/admins-and-slack) -- install the app and create a feed for the specific user).